# Should a markdown parser be client or server side

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently working on a PHP project, which should use markdown to display some text.
The question I ask myself now since there are markdown parsers for javascript and PHP is if I should parse the markdown Server or Client Side.
Pros Server-side:

- Always the same, even on clients which have javascript disabled.

Pros Client-side:

- More dynamic allows for Preview function.
- Uses Clients-Resources instead of the Servers.

Did I miss anything?
What would you suggest?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why not both? render on clients where it works, have server-side for fallback on old/broken clients.

Comment: Good Idea! didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by so-called Isomorphic Javascript or Universal Javascript, I suggest you to make the first rendering on server side; then when you update your page —using ajax— you make the rendering on client side. Doing so you would get the pros of both solutions:

- a fast initial rendering of the page (no need to wait for the JS libraries to be loaded)
- a reduced server load for following requests
- an up-to-date user experience for edition